# jsp color coded view in Netbeans

Tags: jsp, netbeans-7, code-formatting

I am working on JSP in Netbeans 7.0 and right now the jsp code looks like a plaintext notepad data with no color coding for different codes blocks like java code. Is there any way I can make netbeabs to display such formatted code for JSP?
The project is a Java Free Form Project, will need a way for Netbeans to overlook the project type if it expects the project to be of 'web application' type for JSP code formatting.

I am also not able to set the breakpoints in JSP using Netbeans right now and jsut read it online that this is possible for the embedded java part in the jsp. how do I setup Netbeans so that I can do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you need it to be a Java Free Form Project? You could create a new Web Application project and the JSP markup will be colorized.

Comment: The project is setup in netbeans only for code viewing/modificiation and  debugging. Its not Built or Run from the IDE... I am using text-pad to configure build commands to run my project. Hence Its configured as a Java free form project. I did setup Web Application project and the JSP code is now colorized. Only Question is If I can configure the entire project in the Netbeans to even build and run the web application. We use ANT for building, JBOSS AS and extensively use AOPs, EXTJS with JSP